# SelectMany to Dictionary problems

Tags: c#, linq

I am struggling with a `Linq` statement to get get a list of items from within a list of items and convert to a dictionary.

I have a list of "Windows" that have a list of "Controls" but one control type also has a list of controls and I cant seem to figure it out (and just when I thought I understood Linq:))

The current working nested foreach loop

```
    public static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, bool>> _windowControlVisibilityMap = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, bool>>();

    public static void RegisterControlVisibility(IEnumerable<GUIWindow> windows)
    {
        _windowControlVisibilityMap.Clear();
        foreach (var window in windows)
        {
            var controlMap = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
            foreach (var control in window.Controls)
            {
                if (control is GUIGroup)
                {
                    foreach (var grpControl in (control as GUIGroup).Controls)
                    {
                        controlMap.Add(grpControl.ControlId, grpControl.IsWindowOpenVisible);
                    }
                }
                controlMap.Add(control.ControlId, control.IsWindowOpenVisible);
            }

            _windowControlVisibilityMap.Add(window.WindowId, controlMap);
        }
    }
```

My rediculous attempt at a Linq query to do the same. (which does not work)

```
    public static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, bool>> _windowControlVisibilityMap = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, bool>>();

    public static void RegisterControlVisibility2(IEnumerable<GUIWindow> windows)
    {
        _windowControlVisibilityMap.Clear();
        foreach (var window in windows)
        {
            var dictionary = window.Controls.Select(k => new KeyValuePair<int, bool>(k.ControlId, k.IsWindowOpenVisible))
                .Concat(window.Controls.OfType<GUIGroup>().SelectMany(grp => grp.Controls)
                .Select(k => new KeyValuePair<int, bool>(k.ControlId, k.IsWindowOpenVisible)));

           // _windowControlVisibilityMap.Add(window.WindowId, dictionary);
        }
    }
```

If someone could point me in the right direction to get this Linq statement working it would be awesome :)

Here is some mock objects to help you help me, LOL

```
public class GUIWindow
{
    public int WindowId { get; set; }
    public List<GUIControl> Controls { get; set; }
}

public class GUIControl
{
    public int ControlId { get; set; }
    public bool IsWindowOpenVisible { get; set; }
}

public class GUIGroup : GUIControl
{
    public List<GUIControl> Controls { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Each Control has Controls property, and you can't achieve that you want using nested loop, you need recursion.

Comment: @Hamlet Hakobyan, Only GUIGroup has a set of controls, and a GUIGroup cannot contain anothet GUIGroup so I don't think I need recursion, Thaks

Comment: It is not clear from the hierarchy of classes that you have provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```
window.Controls.Select(x => new { x.ControlId, x.IsWindowOpenVisible })
      .Concat(window.Controls
                    .OfType<GUIGroup>()
                    .SelectMany(x => x.Controls)
                    .Select(x => new { x.ControlId, x.IsWindowOpenVisible }))
      .ToDictionary(x => x.ControlId, x => x.IsWindowOpenVisible);
```

---

But Hamlet has a valid point: Each control inside a `GUIGroup` can be another `GUIGroup`. You need recursion to solve this:

```
Func<IEnumerable<GUIControl>, IEnumerable<Tuple<int, bool>> getValues = null;
getValues = x => x.Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.ControlId, x.IsWindowOpenVisible))
                  .Concat(getValues(window.Controls
                                          .OfType<GUIGroup>()
                                          .SelectMany(x => x.Controls)));

getValues(window.Controls).ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2);
```

Comment: I think the OP requires to add the Control itself as well (GUIControl or not).

Comment: @ErenErsönmez: I don't follow. Every control is a `GUIControl`. Please have a look at the class hierarchy the OP posted.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth, Those classes are just test data, there are about 20 GUIControl types only GUIGroup has a list of controls, but GUIGroup cannot contain a GUIGroup so this is perfect for my case.